# There is non-stop reloading of the page Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9

When you go to the page with Google Maps, the page is continuously reloading.
Нow to fix it ?

Comment: check to console log , it might be an error with google maps js

Comment: VM1888 util.js:221 Google Maps JavaScript API warning: SensorNotRequired
this error?

Comment: and [get] errors

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39090691/google-maps-api-warning-sensornotrequired?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: did not help remove [&sensor=false]

Comment: how do you use google map? with api token or without? or it is built in with your webshop?

Comment: all done. i understand my problem
Thank you for attention